# Invalid Datatype with user defined function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I created this package and function to return a sequence of dates, given a start date and stop date (optional).
The package compiles and I can see that it is there with no errors in TOAD.   Anytime I try to execute the function, I receive an error stating:

```
[Error] Execution (10: 8): ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

I do have the right privileges as Ive created other packages with procs and functions; therefore, I'm sure its due to problems with my code.

The logic is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PKG AS


   TYPE table_of_dates IS TABLE OF date;
   
   FUNCTION get_date_table(p_begin in date
                          ,p_stop in date default sysdate
                          ,p_next in integer default 1)
        RETURN table_of_dates;
   
END TEST_PKG;

/



CREATE OR REPLACE package body TEST_PKG as


function get_date_table(p_begin in date
                       ,p_stop in date default sysdate
                       ,p_next in integer default 1)
        RETURN table_of_dates
         IS
            
            date_table    table_of_dates;
            
         BEGIN
            
            with date_sq as (
                select 
                    p_begin begin_date
                    ,p_stop end_date from dual
            )
            select
                d.begin_date + level - p_next
            bulk collect into date_table
            from date_sq d
            where
                1=1
            /* TODO: Check this math */
            connect by level <= (d.end_date - d.begin_date) + p_step
            ;


        RETURN date_table;
    END get_date_table;

end TEST_PKG;
/
```

Some example code to try to test the function is:

```
select TEST_PKG.get_date_table(sysdate) from dual; --  <--causes error shown above
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use that type at SQL level (you do), then you have to create it at SQL level, not within the package.

```
SQL> create or replace type table_of_dates is table of date;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Package spec:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PKG AS
  2
  3
  4  --   TYPE table_of_dates IS TABLE OF date;
  5
  6     FUNCTION get_date_table(p_begin in date
  7                            ,p_stop in date default sysdate
  8                            ,p_next in integer default 1)
  9          RETURN table_of_dates;
 10
 11  END TEST_PKG;
 12
 13  /

Package created.
```

Package body: what is `p_step` at line #25? You never declared it, so I commented it.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE package body TEST_PKG as
  2
  3  function get_date_table(p_begin in date
  4                         ,p_stop in date default sysdate
  5                         ,p_next in integer default 1)
  6          RETURN table_of_dates
  7           IS
  8
  9              date_table    table_of_dates;
 10
 11           BEGIN
 12
 13              with date_sq as (
 14                  select
 15                      p_begin begin_date
 16                      ,p_stop end_date from dual
 17              )
 18              select
 19                  d.begin_date + level - p_next
 20              bulk collect into date_table
 21              from date_sq d
 22              where
 23                  1=1
 24              /* TODO: Check this math */
 25              connect by level <= (d.end_date - d.begin_date) -- + p_step
 26              ;
 27
 28
 29          RETURN date_table;
 30      END get_date_table;
 31
 32  end TEST_PKG;
 33  /

Package body created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * From table(test_pkg.get_date_table(date '2021-07-15'));

COLUMN_VAL
----------
15.07.2021
16.07.2021
17.07.2021
18.07.2021
19.07.2021

SQL>
```

Seems to be OK (as far as the error you reported is concerned).

Comment: Hello.  Thank you for the response and detailed explanation.  Since I want to be able to use this function from the SQL level, is there another way to return this data without having to declare the type in each session?

Comment: @Feyam: two points: (1) the CREATE TYPE is persistent, not specific to the session, so you will not need to re-create it, and (2) a **pipelined** table function can return a PL/SQL type back to SQL. I am not sure why pipelined table functions are treated differently from other table functions in this regard, but they are... To make this a piplined table function write `RETURN table_of_dates PIPELINED` in function spec and body, then remove `RETURN date_table;` and instead iterate over date_table and do `PIPE ROW (date_table(i));` for each element.

Comment: @GeorgeEadon Thank you so much.  I was able to modify my code to use the pipelined table approach and it works perfectly.  I still need to look into this further so I can truly understand why it works that way but now I have a great starting point.  Thanks again!

Comment: @littlefoot, thank you for your help with my original error as well!